# Limit of function involving floor function

Tags: limits

What would be 
$$
\lim_{x\to o}\sum_{i=1}^{10}x[i/x]
$$ 
using the fact that $\lim_{x\to 0} x[1/x]=1$. Is the limit in question $55$?

Comment: It should be the case, if you know the fact.

Answer (score 0):

$$x\left\lfloor\frac ix\right\rfloor=i-x\left\{\frac ix\right\}.$$

As the fractional parts are bounded, the second term vanishes in the limit and

$$\lim_{x\to0}\sum_{i=1}^{10}x\left\lfloor\frac ix\right\rfloor=\sum_{i=1}^{10}i.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\dfrac1{n+1}<x\leq\dfrac1n$

$\sum \dfrac n{n+1}*i <S\leq\sum \dfrac{n+1}n*i$

Then Left and Right converge to $\sum i$.